# Calling .dll in linux environment in c++

Tags: linux, dll, cross-platform, porting, winelib

I have windows dynamic linked library which I want to access from Linux environment. I don't have the source code of that library, so I cannot build .so file.

Is there a way by using `Winelib` or any other library or tool for converting library file to .so file, so that I can call functions defined in that library?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do it, because the DLL cannot run in Linux enviromnemt all by itself. It will probably rely on `user32.dll` `msvcrt.dll` and friends at runtime, so you'll have to provide those files as well.

You can use [winelib](http://wiki.winehq.org/Winelib), but it doesn't just convert a `.dll` to an `.so`. You'll have to link the whole project that wants to call the DLL against winelib, and include the DLL itself with your app at runtime. If you are trying to port a Windows app to Linux, winelib will be able to convert your makefile for you, but it's far from automatic for complex projects.